# Quick stream from file which exists

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I implement live streaming **from mp4 video file which exists on the path** with ffmpeg under hls format.

When my video file have the quality greater than **hd720** , in encoding there are so many delays for creating **.ts** fragments.

I mean the **.ts** fragments slowly produced on my path,and because of it I have so many delays in showing the stream.
Here is my ffmpeg code for streaming:

```
ffmpeg -re -i 123.mp4 -s cga -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac 200p/out.m3u8 
              -s nhd -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac 360p/out.m3u8 
              -s hd480 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac 480p/out.m3u8 
              -s hd720 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac 720p/out.m3u8
              -s hd1080 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac 1080p/out.m3u8
```

And here is the console output:

```
    ffmpeg -re -i ../files/412-887123464/video/412-887123464.mp4 -s cga -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac ../fil
        es/412-887123464/video/200p/out.m3u8  -s nhd -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac ../files/412-887123464/video/360p/out.m3u8 -s hd480 -f hls -
        hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac ../files/412-887123464/video/480p/out.m3u8 -s hd720 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac ../files/412-88
        7123464/video/720p/out.m3u8 -s hd1080 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac ../files/412-887123464/video/1080p/out.m3u8
        ffmpeg version N-82225-gb4e9252 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
          built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
          configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --e
        nable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcac
        a --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-lib
        opencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr
         --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwa
        vpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zl
        ib
          libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
          libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
          libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
          libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
          libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
          libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
          libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
          libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
        Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../files/412-887123464/video/412-887123464.mp4':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.31.100
          Duration: 00:05:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3108 kb/s
            Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2976 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50
        tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
            Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c53f00] using SAR=10/9
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c53f00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c53f00] profile High, level 1.3
        Output #0, hls, to '../files/412-887123464/video/200p/out.m3u8':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
            Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 320x200 [SAR 10:9 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 libx264
            Side data:
              cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
            Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
        [libx264 @ 0000000001f87180] using SAR=1/1
        [libx264 @ 0000000001f87180] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 0000000001f87180] profile High, level 3.0
        Output #1, hls, to '../files/412-887123464/video/360p/out.m3u8':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
            Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 libx264
            Side data:
              cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
            Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c55ba0] using SAR=640/639
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c55ba0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 0000000001c55ba0] profile High, level 3.0
        Output #2, hls, to '../files/412-887123464/video/480p/out.m3u8':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
            Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 libx264
            Side data:
              cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
            Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca0220] using SAR=1/1
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca0220] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca0220] profile High, level 3.1
        Output #3, hls, to '../files/412-887123464/video/720p/out.m3u8':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
            Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 libx264
            Side data:
              cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
            Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca23e0] using SAR=1/1
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca23e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 0000000001ca23e0] profile High, level 4.0
        Output #4, hls, to '../files/412-887123464/video/1080p/out.m3u8':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
            Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 libx264
            Side data:
              cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
            Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
              encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
        Stream mapping:
          Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
          Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
          Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
          Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
          Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
          Stream #0:1 -> #2:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
          Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
          Stream #0:1 -> #3:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
          Stream #0:0 -> #4:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
          Stream #0:1 -> #4:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
        Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 7600 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:05:04.06 bitrate=N/A speed=0.835x
video:294980kB audio:23995kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] frame I:33    Avg QP:19.93  size: 11412
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] frame P:2281  Avg QP:23.72  size:  3112
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] frame B:5286  Avg QP:28.59  size:   446
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] consecutive B-frames:  4.3%  6.9%  5.9% 82.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] mb I  I16..4: 12.9% 42.9% 44.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] mb P  I16..4:  1.3%  4.4%  2.3%  P16..4: 41.4% 22.0% 15.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:13.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 35.2%  5.9%  2.1%  direct: 3.0%  skip:53.6%  L0:35.3% L1:48.0% BI:16.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] 8x8 transform intra:53.4% inter:57.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 70.6% 89.7% 67.6% inter: 18.1% 20.3% 7.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 24%  6% 45%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 14% 19%  5%  5%  7%  5% 10%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 15% 15%  6%  6%  7%  6%  8%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 17% 28% 14%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:26.3% UV:12.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] ref P L0: 58.7% 24.7% 10.9%  4.8%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] ref B L0: 92.6%  5.8%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] ref B L1: 96.3%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d33f00] kb/s:258.68
[aac @ 00000000005fc9e0] Qavg: 686.637
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] frame I:31    Avg QP:19.77  size: 29228
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] frame P:2040  Avg QP:23.08  size:  8765
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] frame B:5529  Avg QP:27.28  size:  1471
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  4.2%  2.4% 92.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] mb I  I16..4:  8.3% 58.8% 32.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] mb P  I16..4:  3.2%  9.5%  2.6%  P16..4: 41.5% 19.5% 11.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:12.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 34.5%  5.8%  1.7%  direct: 2.7%  skip:54.7%  L0:35.9% L1:49.5% BI:14.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] 8x8 transform intra:61.2% inter:67.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 55.8% 84.8% 51.3% inter: 15.6% 19.3% 3.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 29%  8% 39%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 17% 21%  5%  5%  7%  5%  8%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 18% 15%  6%  7%  7%  6%  7%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 18% 27% 13%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] Weighted P-Frames: Y:22.3% UV:12.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] ref P L0: 58.5% 23.4% 12.2%  5.2%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] ref B L0: 93.1%  5.3%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] ref B L1: 96.6%  3.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002017180] kb/s:708.47
[aac @ 0000000001d35200] Qavg: 686.637
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] frame I:31    Avg QP:19.63  size: 41522
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] frame P:2025  Avg QP:22.86  size: 13415
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] frame B:5544  Avg QP:26.52  size:  2471
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  3.9%  2.8% 92.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] mb I  I16..4: 10.6% 62.4% 26.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] mb P  I16..4:  4.7% 12.4%  2.6%  P16..4: 41.1% 17.8%  9.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:11.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.5%  0.1%  B16..8: 34.0%  5.5%  1.4%  direct: 2.9%  skip:55.3%  L0:36.7% L1:50.2% BI:13.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] 8x8 transform intra:61.7% inter:71.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.0% 81.9% 43.3% inter: 14.7% 19.7% 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 29%  9% 35%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 19% 22%  5%  5%  6%  5%  7%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 25% 16%  5%  6%  7%  6%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 20% 26% 12%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:18.1% UV:10.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] ref P L0: 59.5% 22.6% 12.6%  4.8%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] ref B L0: 93.6%  5.0%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] ref B L1: 97.1%  2.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d35ba0] kb/s:1109.23
[aac @ 0000000001d828a0] Qavg: 686.637
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] frame I:32    Avg QP:19.45  size: 64737
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] frame P:2104  Avg QP:22.44  size: 23985
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] frame B:5464  Avg QP:25.65  size:  4999
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] consecutive B-frames:  1.2%  7.7%  3.2% 87.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] mb I  I16..4: 12.5% 70.0% 17.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] mb P  I16..4:  6.7% 17.1%  1.8%  P16..4: 40.7% 14.9%  6.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:12.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  0.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 32.5%  4.7%  1.0%  direct: 2.9%  skip:57.4%  L0:37.6% L1:51.6% BI:10.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] 8x8 transform intra:65.7% inter:77.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 39.5% 76.4% 32.4% inter: 13.2% 19.8% 1.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 27% 10% 31%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 18% 23%  4%  5%  5%  4%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 20% 15%  5%  7%  7%  6%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 19% 27% 12%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] Weighted P-Frames: Y:10.5% UV:6.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] ref P L0: 62.3% 20.4% 12.7%  4.3%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] ref B L0: 93.4%  5.2%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] ref B L1: 97.7%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7f880] kb/s:2101.26
[aac @ 0000000001d81560] Qavg: 686.637
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] frame I:33    Avg QP:18.36  size: 98904
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] frame P:3180  Avg QP:21.67  size: 33377
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] frame B:4387  Avg QP:24.61  size:  7729
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] consecutive B-frames:  2.7% 55.9% 15.6% 25.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] mb I  I16..4: 22.4% 66.9% 10.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] mb P  I16..4:  9.9% 17.8%  0.7%  P16..4: 40.4%  9.2%  3.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:19.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] mb B  I16..4:  0.8%  1.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 30.2%  2.6%  0.4%  direct: 1.7%  skip:63.0%  L0:38.1% L1:54.9% BI: 7.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] 8x8 transform intra:62.5% inter:82.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 25.4% 59.5% 11.6% inter: 9.6% 16.3% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] i16 v,h,dc,p: 33% 28% 15% 24%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 20% 29%  3%  3%  4%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 25% 16%  4%  6%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 21% 28% 12%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.7% UV:3.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] ref P L0: 70.0% 18.6%  8.3%  3.1%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] ref B L0: 91.4%  7.6%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] ref B L1: 99.0%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001d7fd60] kb/s:3771.31
[aac @ 0000000001d823e0] Qavg: 686.637
```

But I don't have any problem for streaming files with creating resolutions from a file which have lower orginal quality than **hd1080**
What I can to do?

Comment: Maybe your computer can't handle encoding all of these at once, but you didn't provide the complete console output so we can only guess.

Comment: I believe you are encoding too slowly. Try a faster [preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), use the [tee muxer](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer) to encode the audio only once, and eliminate one or two of the smaller sized outputs. If it still is too slow use a [hardware assisted encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard With setting **preset** and using **tee muxer**, stream speed is better now for streaming from video which have [**hd1080**](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Video-size)  size. But stream from video which have 4k orginal size, delay exists. A question for **using hardware assisted encoder**.
for using of hardware accleration must be have graphic card,that's right?

Comment: Yes, you need supported hardware to use such an encoder (or decoder), and your `ffmpeg` may have to be compiled to support it too. You should show your new command using tee muxer with the 4K input; maybe there is something else to suggest.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard,Thank you for great assistance,sure ,I post an answer with the new command I'm using.please view it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new command which I used With setting **preset** and using **tee muxer** with the 4K input,it's better now for [**hd1080**](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Video-size) input but with 4k input delay exists.

```
 ffmpeg -re -i ../files/412-983590871/video/412-983590871.mp4 
       -filter_complex [0:v]split=7[s0][s1][s2][s3][s4][s5][s6];
        [s0]scale=3840:-1[v0];
        [s1]scale=2560:-1[v1];
        [s2]scale=1920:-1[v2];
        [s3]scale=1280:-1[v3];
        [s4]scale=960:-1[v4];
        [s5]scale=640:-1[v5];
        [s6]scale=320:-1[v6]
       -map [v0] -map [v1] -map [v2] -map [v3] -map [v4] -map [v5] -map [v6] 
       -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -hls_list_size 0 -preset ultrafast -g 48 
    "[select=\'v:0,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/2160p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:1,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/1440p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:2,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/1080p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:3,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/720p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:4,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/480p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:5,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/360p/out.m3u8|
    [select=\'v:6,a\']../files/412-983590871/video/200p/out.m3u8"
```

Comment: I guess since you posted it as an answer it means you found a solution that works for you. Command seems fine, although I don't see why you need so many output sizes. I'd probably use `-2` instead of `-1` for scale.

Comment: Yes,but I want to use **hardware assisted encoder** solution which you mentioned to me, for the complete answer, and when I used it on my program I post it as true final answer instantly. Thank you.